# Mean residual service time of M/G/1 queue

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, exponential-distribution, poisson-process, queueing-theory

I have a queue where jobs arrive as a Poisson process with rate $\lambda=\frac{1}{6}$ jobs per minute. The process time of a job is exponentially distributed with mean time 3 minutes with probability $\frac{2}{5}$ or is the sum of two independent exponential distributions with each a mean time of 3 minutes with probability $\frac{3}{5}$. I want to compute the expected residual service time.

I know it is given by $\mathbb{E}[R]=\frac{\mathbb{E}[B^2]}{2\mathbb{E}[B]}$ where $B$ denotes the service time distribution.

So I compute $\mathbb{E}[B]=\frac{2}{5}\cdot 3+\frac{3}{5}\cdot 6=\frac{24}{5}$ and
$\mathbb{E}[B^2]=\frac{2}{5}\cdot 3^{2}+\frac{3}{5}6^2=\frac{126}{5}$.

This then gives me $\mathbb{E}[R]=\frac{21}{8}$. The solution of this exercise gives that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[R]=\frac{5}{8}\cdot 3+\frac{3}{8}\cdot 6=\frac{33}{8}
\end{equation}

I don't understand which method is used in the solution and why it would give a different result than my approach. Could someone help me by explaining what happens in the given solution and/or is wrong with my approach?

Comment: The answer is indeed $33/8$.  You are not computing the second moment correctly. $$E[B^2] = E[B^2|\mbox{Type 1}](2/5) + E[B^2|\mbox{Type 2}](3/5)$$  Now given type 1, $B$ is exponential with parameter $\lambda = 1/3$ and so $E[B|\mbox{Type 1}] = 1/\lambda=3$ and $$E[B^2|\mbox{Type 1}] = Var(B|\mbox{Type 1}) + E[B|\mbox{Type 1}]^2=2/\lambda^2=18$$ In short, the second moment is not just the square of the first moment: $$E[X^2] = Var(X) + E[X]^2$$